# Grocery CRUD: To change the integer time to a timestamp when state=Read

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

While using **CRUD**,
I have a database field "created"(`dataType=>integer`).

When `state='list'` the following code converts the integer to date format and display:

```
$crud->callback_column('created', array($this,'date_display'));       //where date_display a function to change date format works


 function date_display($value, $row){
    return  date('d M Y H:i:s',$value);
 }
```

Whereas when `state='read'` the above code does not work and neither the function `change_field_type` works:

```
  $crud->change_field_type('created', 'datetime');
```

How to change the integer time to date format in case of `state='read'`?